# Reliable way to get all user directories?

Tags: windows

After much googling, I'm still not finding what I'm looking for.

I simply want to find the names of every user account on my machine. For example, in the C:\Users\ directory, there will be directories for every user on the machine. There must be a more elegant way than simply regexing the usernames from the users directory, though.

These are not the same names that are shown in Win32_UserAccount WMI query. When I execute:

```
Get-WMIObject -query 'SELECT * from Win32_UserAccount'
```

... I get names such as 'Administrator', 'Default Account', etc. These are not the names I am looking for. I want the names that are shown in C:\Users\

What is the most programmatic way to get the names of all the users in the c:\Users folder?

Thanks!

Comment: You can filter the list to only include enabled accounts, e.g. `SELECT * from Win32_UserAccount where Disabled=FALSE`.  If an account is enabled but has never logged on, then it won't have a profile yet in "Users".

Comment: The problem with querying UserAccounts is that it's not giving me the correct user name associated with the account.

Comment: I thought you just wanted the account names, for which `Win32_UserAccount` is giving you the right names, without question. But if what you really want is the local profile path instead, try this snippet of PowerShell code: `gwmi Win32_UserProfile | select @{Name="Name"; Expression={gwmi Win32_UserAccount -Filter "SID='$($_.SID)'" | select -ExpandProperty Caption}}, LocalPath`

Comment: Interesting, but not quite what I'm looking for. I can get the list of SID's convert them to account names, but I was hoping that there was a more efficient way to simply get the account names of all the users on the machine. Alas, I was wrong.

Comment: We appear to be talking past each other. `Win32_UserAccount` does return all of the account names. Exactly which name do you need -- the full display name?

Comment: I mean the names of the users, as in C:\Users\XXXXXXXX.

Comment: The directories in "C:\Users" are user profiles, i.e. the `LocalPath` from `Win32_UserProfile`, for which I gave a PowerShell example. The directory name for the user profile is not necessarily the account name (e.g. the user name was changed), and all user profiles are not necessarily located in "C:\Users".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just gathering all directories in the c:\users\ directory and regexing out the name of the folders in that directory.